Help identifying a corn brick (Duplo or Mega Bloks?)
I've bought some used Duplo parts which where mixed with other clone brands and I found these corn pieces. I want to know if this is Duplo or some legit clone brand such Mega Bloks and not some cheap Chinese clone which I don't dare let my child play with. I can't find any identification on the piece anywhere except "B2" at the bottom.



Does it fit onto a Lego/Duplo stud?

ah. yes it does

Which one? Lego or Duplo studs?

Ah, sorry, Duplo.

It belongs to Mega Bloks McQueen set or Thomas the Train from about 2010 set. I have four of them from my child’s set he had.


Ah yes you are right! I find pictures of it now when searching for "Mega Bloks McQueen" ( https://www.takefiveaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/megabloks-included.jpg ) Thanks!

Since the part is a) lacking any of the signature markings, b) is not found among the list of Duplo plant parts and c) does not appear in Bricklink when searching for the word "corn", it's a safe bet to say this is not a piece produced by LEGO.
If it is a MegaBlock or other brand with appropriate reputation, I can't say - partly because those brands lack part inventories like Bricklink, and partially because I don't know which brands would be considered legit enough.

I don't know if it's different for DUPLO, but ordinary sized LEGO typically doesn't have hexagonal antistuds, that's possibly a fourth reason.

thanks, all good information, not LEGO then. I'm hoping to verify it to be MegaBloks but seems to be tricky then.

Another thing that bothered me about this part is the edge between the yellow and the green on the piece.  LEGO is usually smart enough not to paint themselves into those quality corners.
